# selecting mysql database's table in php $query

Tags: php, mysql, database, http

I am sending from arduino usinh http 1.1 (x-www-form-urlencoded) temperature and humidity readings to mysql database. if I use commented part of the following code, everything works (tab12 is the name of the table in mysql database). But I would like to arduino send the name of the table, so I could use the same add.php file to play with multiple arduinos. The thing is, I don't understand how to correctly put the table name from `$tabid=$_POST["tabid"];` to query.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

$link=Connection();

$tabid=$_POST["tabid"];
$temp1=$_POST["temp1"];
$hum1=$_POST["hum1"];

//  $query = "INSERT INTO `tab12` (`temperature`, `humidity`) 
//      VALUES ('".$temp1."','".$hum1."')"; 

$query = "INSERT INTO `"tabid"` (`temperature`, `humidity`) 
    VALUES ('".$tabid."','".$temp1."','".$hum1."')"; 

mysql_query($query,$link);
mysql_close($link);

header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's not as hard as you think](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would concatenate just as you would with any variable:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `" . $tabid . "` (`temperature`, `humidity`) 
VALUES ('".$temp1."','".$hum1."')";
```

In addition your number of `columns` and `values` *must* match.